# Как релизовать такую функцию на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, json, mysql

Добрый день!

У меня возник вопрос. Есть в базе данных 3 таблицы: `user`, `items` и `useritems`. Мне нужно сделать запрос к таблице `user` и выяснить, есть ли такой пользователь в базе, если есть, то выводим его `ИМЯ` и все предметы, которые у него есть, а если пользователя нет с таким ИМЕНЕМ, то просто выводим сообщение, что пользователь добавлен в базу данных и автоматически добавить ему предмет.

В таблице `useritems` у меня 3 поля `id`, `uid`, и `itmid` и теперь я не могу понять, как добавить туда пользователя и присвоить ему любой предмет из таблицы `items`. Так как у меня при клике на кнопку "добавить" добавляется только пользователь в таблицу `user`.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`uname`) VALUES ('$nambreUsuario');
```

А вот как добавить предмет и пользователя  в таблице таблице `useritems`, я ума не приложу. И при этом должно, чтобы и в таблице `user` и таблице `useritems` пользователь был под одним `id`.

Скрипт вывода информации о пользователе.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#resultados").hide();
    $('#buscar_usuario').autocomplete({
        source: 'ajax.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#resultados').slideUp('slow', function () {
                $('#resultados').html('<h2>Информация о пользователе<h2>' + '<img src="' + ui.item.foto + '"/>' + '<strong>Пользователь: </strong>' + ui.item.value + '<br/>' + '<strong>Количество предметов:
    </strong>' + ui.item.descripcion);
            });
            $('#resultados').slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Скрипт вывода информации что пользователь добавлен:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#result').click(function(){

       $.post("ajax.php",{"buscar_usuario":$("#buscar_usuario").val()},
        $("#resultados").slideToggle("slow"),
        $(this).toggleClass("active")
                )
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `имя тяблицы` SET `поле`='значение', `поле`='значение';");
```

Comment: У меня теперь такая проблемма. В таблицу добовляется но почемуто пустая строка. Вот мой запрос

$name = $_POST['namber_usuarios'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (namber_usuarios) VALUES ($name)"

Comment: 1. Запустите обработчик запроса не через ajax, а напрямую.
2. сделайте `echo $sql;` перед выполнением запроса.
3. поставьте **;** после назначения переменной $sql.

Comment: `;` не ставьте - беспполезное занятие.
P.S. Сделайте там, где у вас запрос

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Если ошибки нет, то скорее всего не приходит `$_POST['namber_usuarios']`, ну а если есть - поправьте :)

Comment: Если не поставить **;** в конце, после присваивания, то вылезет ошибка, так что не говорите глупости, @AlexWindHope.

Comment: Не приходит `$_POST['namber_usuarios']`. В чем может быть проблема?